# Errors in crontab file, can't install - only on CentOS 7, not CentOS 6.4?

Tags: centos, centos6, cron, centos7

CentOS 6.4 is happy with this, but CentOS 7 tells me "errors in crontab file, can't install.". What's wrong with this crontab file (just the 2 lines)?

```
0 0 * * * /home/web/backup-db.sh
0 1 * * * /home/web/backup-files.sh
```

I've tried this [based on this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31898344/errors-in-crontab-file-cant-install), this doesn't work either:

```
every '0 0 * * *' do /home/web/backup-db.sh
every '0 1 * * *' do /home/web/backup-files.sh
```

It's not permissions on those files, because this doesn't work either:

```
1 1 * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate -s time-1.ncsu.edu
```

ntupdate is correctly installed, and in that location. So it's something about my crontab syntax I think - ideas?

Comment: Please explain what you did when trying to install the file (also the `every ....` from the answer you linked is valid only in the context of that ruby script, it's not valid syntax for a crontab.

Comment: If you open in the crontab in vim and do `:set list` are there any unexpected hidden characters, like carriage-returns?

Comment: @Sven - good to know that that middle block is ruby. The other blocks I've tried I've just installed by saving the file - ie.., 'crontab -e' to edit crontab, save. I'm using emacs to edit the file.

Comment: @shearn89, No unexpected hidden characters.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a # on a single line at the end of the file fixed it. It was a premature EOF issue.

Answer (score 0):

If this is /etc/crontab, you're missing a username in there.

Try this:

```
0 0 * * * root /home/web/backup-db.sh
0 1 * * * root /home/web/backup-files.sh
```

Comment: I tried that, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and adding # did not help.
I just figure out that the error is because of my bad timing at each line. Be aware that there is five place to put time. I accidentally put 6 items!!

*bad request:*

```
1 0 * * * * /home/web/backup-db.sh
```

you should **omit one *** and the crontab will install and work fine.

correct:

```
 1 0 * * * /home/web/backup-db.sh
```

I just write this answer for others that may have the same problem!

Comment: That was your typo, but not the error from the question.